# PHP chmod() is not working on server

Tags: php, linux, apache, unix, centos

I have thoroughly searched stackoverflow and other online resources but nothing worked.

Basically, I want to write new content to a file on server. I am using following code to test it.

**Code:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$my_file = 'test_file.php';

$permission = chmod($my_file, 0775);
echo "Permission";
var_dump($permission);exit;
```

It always returns false and shows a warning that `chmod()` is not permissible.

I don't want to use ftp solution for this. So, please tell me what's the reason `chmod()` not working as well as is there any other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: and `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);` gave you what exactly?

Comment: Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /home/new/domains/test.new.com.eu/public_html/test_perm.php on line 1

Comment: The user is not root so you have no permission to change the CHMOD. The webserver user needs to have these permissions first.

Comment: You should do a chown 644 USER:GROUP test_file.php on the webserver on the php file. Change the user and the group to the php user to change the ownership of the file. Than you should have permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the web server user (`www-data` on most Linux flavours) doesn't have permission to change the permissions of the file `test_file.php`.

To fix this, you can just run `chmod 644 www-data:www-data test_file.php` (replace `www-data` with your web server user) and you should now be able to change the permissions with PHP's `chmod()`.

Comment: Can't I resolve this issue solely by using PHP script?

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer no, because PHP (or more accurately,  `www-data`) isn't allowed to modify the permissions of the file. However, once you've done the above, you will be able to.